# Dell OpenManage and Exchange 2010 SP1

Tags: exchange-2010, dell, dell-openmanage

I inherited an Exchange 2010 SP1 server from a previous sysadmin, and it was running on Dell hardware. However, I now suspect that the RAM is throwing out errors. The trouble is, the server does not have Dell OpenManage on it, so there is no way (I think) for me to check the RAM status without taking the server down.

Is there any reason that Dell OpenManage shouldn't be installed on and Exchange 2010 SP1 server? I'm not sure if the previous sysadmin didn't install OpenManage due to accident or design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason not to have it installed.

If I'm remembering correctly, DOMSA will show you the status of the memory but has no way to run diagnostics. For that you'll need to download and run the Dell diagnostic tools.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Mostly its just single bit errors and I need to re-seat the memory, so I don't need diagnostics just yet.

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no reason it can not be installed. It may not be necessary, though. If a DRAC card is installed, you should theoretically be able to check the System Event Log (or whatever the DRAC equivalent is) for detected RAM errors.